# How to change Grails 3 SDK path in IntelliJ project once created?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, grails-3.0.9, grails-3.0.10

I would like to change my project from Grails from `3.0.9` to `3.0.10` since latter contains Promise API.

How to do that in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

in the `gradle.properties` file change

```
grailsVersion=3.0.10
```

also in the `build.gradle` change

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
}
```

Comment: How will it know the path to Grails SDK?

Comment: you dont need to set grails sdk. only jdk. grails convert your code to byte code then uses jvm to run

Comment: Then why it asks me for the path if I am creating Grails project from scratch?

Comment: if you need to see where it is located after creating the project then go settings >>> language & frmawork >>> grails

Comment: How does it know WHICH grails to use to convert the code to byte code?  (Grails is not an option under Language & Framework even though this is a grails 3 project)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the grails version in gradle.properties.  The gradle build script will pull the required jar files from the grails repo specified in your build file.